# Nginx rewrite priority

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I have some specific redirects and I want anything else just to be forwarded to the same file on another domain. So I need to set priorities in the nginx redirects. Example:

// Specific redirects:

```
rewrite ^/oldname1/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/newmapname2? permanent;
rewrite ^/oldname2$ http://www.newdomain.com/newfilename3? permanent;
```

// Anything else must be forward to the same file on new domain:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 permanent;
```

I know that in .htaccess I can just put them in the right order and it works. However in Nginx this doesn't seem to work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Rewrite priority rules are simple: first matching rule wins. If you have problem with it, you should post full config

Comment: Also post the requested URLs, the expected redirect and the actual redirect.

Comment: You are right @Alexey, first matching rule wins. It works. Thanks!